# Logback stops deleting archived logs when rolling policy reaches index 996

Tags: java, logging, logback

I've set up Logback for my business applications to keep the last 50MB of archived logs for each application, 10MB for each file, using size and time based rolling policy. Logs are getting consumed by Filebeat and are expected to be deleted soon afterwards.

Works like a charm - old archives are being deleted...until %i index value reaches 996. Then, old logs are rolled over but are no longer deleted, which results in disk space getting filled very quickly. Policy configuration:

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}business-log-${APPLICATION_NAME}-${ROLLING_PATTERN}-%i.json</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>${BUSINESS_APPENDER_MAX_FILE_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
        <totalSizeCap>${BUSINESS_APPENDER_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP:-50MB}</totalSizeCap>
        <maxHistory>${BUSINESS_APPENDER_MAX_HISTORY:-5}</maxHistory>
        <cleanHistoryOnStart>${BUSINESS_APPENDER_CLEAN_HISTORY_ON_START:-true}</cleanHistoryOnStart>
</rollingPolicy>
```

Directory containing log files:

```
...
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10545515 Aug 26 04:54 log-example-application-20210826-1216.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10578986 Aug 26 04:55 log-example-application-20210826-1217.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10551848 Aug 26 04:55 log-example-application-20210826-1218.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10551008 Aug 26 04:55 log-example-application-20210826-1219.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10506275 Aug 26 04:56 log-example-application-20210826-1220.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10534379 Aug 26 04:56 log-example-application-20210826-1221.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10513144 Aug 26 04:56 log-example-application-20210826-1222.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10588197 Aug 26 04:57 log-example-application-20210826-1223.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10532073 Aug 26 04:57 log-example-application-20210826-1224.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10528993 Aug 26 04:57 log-example-application-20210826-1225.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10543370 Aug 26 04:57 log-example-application-20210826-1226.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10558424 Aug 26 04:58 log-example-application-20210826-1227.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10567860 Aug 26 04:58 log-example-application-20210826-1228.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10537785 Aug 26 04:58 log-example-application-20210826-1229.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10573044 Aug 26 04:59 log-example-application-20210826-1230.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10542241 Aug 26 03:40 log-example-application-20210826-996.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10534389 Aug 26 03:40 log-example-application-20210826-997.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10536618 Aug 26 03:41 log-example-application-20210826-998.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      10565976 Aug 26 03:41 log-example-application-20210826-999.json
```

This problem occured many times for different applications, usually when experiencing huge load of incoming logs, e.g. due to issues with connecting to Kafka broker. Has anyone experienced such issue? What could be the solution?